# Implementation of `sequence` with `ap`

Tags: haskell

[Applicative Programming with Effects](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html), the paper from McBride and Paterson, mentions the `sequence` function:

```
sequence :: [IO a ] -> IO [a ]
sequence []       = return []
sequence (c : cs) = return (:) `ap` c `ap` sequence cs
```

where `ap`'s type is:

`ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`

I'm trying to understand the types of the last line's right-side.

How do the types unify (I think that's the correct wording) for `return (:) 'ap' c 'ap' sequence cs`?

It's not clear to me how `return (:)` matches `ap`'s first argument `m (a -> b)`.

```
ghci> :t return (:)
return (:) :: Monad m => m (a -> [a] -> [a])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is... currying!
The first argument to `ap` has type `m (a -> b)`, so the function expects
a value of type `a` and will product a value of type `b`. One possible thing
that `b` could be is another function (i.e. `b` could be unified with `[a] -> [a]`). So, we line things up and get

```
ap         :: Monad m => m (a -> b         ) -> m a -> m b
                                 ==========
return (:) :: Monad m => m (a -> [a] -> [a])
```

The `ap` function performs application of a function in some context (in this case a monad) to a value in that context, it just so happens that it is often used to perform a sequence of partial applications.